# How to build a price generator application- guidelines

Tags: java, software-design

I've recently finished basic Java course so I know to work with classes, inheritance, recursion, linked lists and arrays.

I'm looking to build a price generator application for my business. The application should:

1. Connect to a database so it will be able to fetch rates based on user input.
2. Receive user input- age, sex, product etc.
3. Have a GUI.
4. Return the final price.
5. Should work on mac and windows.

I would appreciate ideas\approaches that would help me start designing this.

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you try the bits you can do as a prototype and then design the system you would have wanted.

Comment: You would be surprised how long you can get just by taking one small step at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very opinion based question (so it might get flagged and closed) but i would recommend that you:

1. Read about the mvc design
2. Read about the DAO design pattern
3. Read about UX design (user experience)
4. Don't be afraid to start experimenting
5. Don't be afraid to throw away a design that doesn't seem like a good idea anymore
6. If you plan on code in java, it'll run the same on both mac and windows

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use netbeans IDE, or use Eclipse IDE with Window Builder Pro. With both of it you can make GUI with drag and drop. For example you can use oracle Database. If you choose Oracle, i can help a bit more.